# Can a router have 5 IPs?

Tags: networking, router, internet, dd-wrt

We have a Linksys wireless G router and a BT connection with 5 IPs.

I have no idea how to set this up. Can this router take 5 IPs? I can't see anywhere on the admin panel to configure this. I have also searched Google but no joy.

Do I need a better router to handle the multiple IPs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most consumer routers are only capable of a single WAN IP address. You will need to use DD-WRT or something stronger if you want to use more than one WAN IP address and route them appropriately.

Comment: what would be a recommended router that can handle this natively to use for this scenario?

Comment: Something running DD-WRT or stronger.

Comment: so if i download one of the builds from http://www.dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database whcih is for the wrt54g and upgrade the firmware on the current panel i will be able to run multiple IPs?

Comment: Yes, but it will take a little more than that to actually *use* them, since the default configuration still assumes a single address. Unless you have experience configuring Linux to have and route multiple addresses on a single interface, I wouldn't worry terribly about it.

Comment: so - what router should i be using that will have multiple IP support? without messing about with linux?

Comment: Something from Cisco that doesn't have "Linksys" in it might do it.

Answer (score 0):

The regular LinkSys home routers typically don't support having more than one IPv4 address (and most don't support IPv6 yet either).  You may have better luck with a custom third-party firmware (which could void your warranty, just in case you weren't aware) or set up a Unix/Linux box with a proper firewall to do the same thing.

DD-WRT (third-party firmware for routers)
  http://www.dd-wrt.com/

Answer (score 0):

Yes and no...

As both the other answers say, typically with home routers, the answer is NO, they use NAT and it only supports a single IP address.

What you can do however is turn NAT off and using direct routing/bridging, giving each machine you want to have a static IP its own, then also if you wish, you can get a different router behind that and assigning that a static IP, then machines behind that can use NAT as standard.

Comment: It's important to note that this configuration idea (although it is a very interesting one) could introduce some serious security risks since these machines (hosts) would be directly accessible from the internet without even the basic protection that NAT provides.